# Matlab overplot comet3 on a surf graph

Tags: matlab, surface

I would like to overplot a comet3 plot over a surf plot, is this possible? hold on did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with the appropriate x,y and z values for the surface you are trying to display.

Simple example:

```
clc
clear

t = -2*pi:pi/100:2*pi;
x = (cos(2*t).^2).*sin(t);
y = (sin(2*t).^2).*cos(t);

%// Create x and y data for the surface plot
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
zz = xx.^2 + yy.^2 - 7;
surf(xx,yy,zz)

hold on

comet3(x,y,t);
```

output:

[image]